# How to get the third string from URL using php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using below code in htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^/?service/abc/([\w-]+)/?$ xyz.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^/?service/pqr/([\w-]+)/?$ xyz.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

to display my URL something like:

```
http://example.com/service/abc/review
http://example.com/service/pqr/review
```

which is working for me. Now my issue is, I have to get `abc` or `pqr` a string from URL and display

I am trying to get the name like

```
$getURL=explode('/', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);// getting service/abc/review
echo $a = next($getURL); //it's displaying only service
```

Or is there any best way?

Woult you help me out ?

Comment: Is `$getURL[1]` what your after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use *one* rule, allow for either `abc` or `pqr` in that position, and append it as an additional GET parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^service/(abc|pqr)/([\w-]+)/?$ xyz.php?service=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

And use `$_GET['service']` to access the value then.

Comment: I want to know after using your code, What should I add on HTML. I tried <a href="<?php echo siteUrl; ?>service/abc/<?php echo $get_name ?>">Click me</a>. is it correct?

Comment: Oh!, sorry that was my fault. give me some time.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the htaccess rules in this way

```
RewriteRule ^/?service/(.*)/(.*)/?$ xyz.php?endpoint=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and retrieve them in xyz.php file

```
var_dump($_GET);
```

Comment: I have a button <a href="<?php echo siteUrl; ?>service/abc/<?php echo $get_name ?>">Click me</a> after clicking on button then it will call xyz.php

Comment: it should, edit the rule and insert the real php filename which have to manage the request. be sure about the path is right